# Dynamic SQL: secure a password parameter from SQL injections

Tags: sql, security, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-injection

As scary as it sounds, an input for a password parameter has to be secured in the following dynamic SQL: `CREATE LOGIN NewLogin WITH PASSWORD='MyStrongPassword'`. A @parameter cannot be used:
like this `PASSWORD=@pwd` (Incorrect syntax near '@pwd' error). With other parameters like table name or user name, it is more or less simple: allow letters, digits and underscores, validate using a simple regex and quotename it. With passwords you have to allow usage of strong chars. 
So should the password be cleared from certain characters like comma, space, etc or is there a better way?

Comment: Umm, you shouldn't be storing passwords in plaintext!

Comment: It is just a placeholder that will be replaced with a real password supplied by a web application user.

Comment: Yes, I gathered that it wouldn't always be "MyStrongPassword"!  What I meant was that you should be applying some sort of cryptographic hash function (MD5, SHA1, etc.) to your password (preferably with a salt), and storing the result instead of the password itself.

Comment: He's not storing the password.  He's calling CREATE LOGIN to create a SQL Server login.

Comment: The question would still remain the same: how to prevent injections. I'd use something like `HashBytes('SHA1', 'SALT123' + 'MyPassword')` and still execute it dynamically. See my point? Additionally, as it was mentioned you cannot create a Login with a parameter. So how would you get whats returned by HashBytes and pass it to CREATE LOGIN? You see I'm not storing it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but you can parametrize sp_addlogin:

```
exec sp_AddLogin @user, @password;
```

Or you can use SMO.

Comment: according to MSDN sp_AddLogin will be deprecated: "This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. Use CREATE LOGIN instead." Thats a great idea to use SMO!